# Добавление к типу WINAPI. int WINAPI, HANDLE WINAPI

Tags: winapi

пишут такие типы как `HANDLE WINAPI` или `int WINAPI` и другие, а что добавление `WINAPI` меняет? И сам по себе `WINAPI` что за тип  ?

Answer (score 1):

Это макрос, определённый в одном из заголовочных файлов

**Что именно** он делает в текущей конфигурации - нужно посмотреть в макросе (а макрос может по-разному развернуться в зависимости от других определений)

Обычно определяет соглашение о вызове `__stdcall`

Answer (score 1):

Символ `WINAPI` никакого отношения к типу не имеет. В Windows API этот макрос используется с функциями и определяет соглашение о вызове (calling convention). Поскольку WinAPI использует [паскалевское соглашение о вызове](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), то этот символ определяется как `__stdcall`.

Поскольку вероятность внезапного изменения соглашения о вызове в WinAPI чуть ниже абсолютного нуля, то этот символ можно было бы вообще не определять, а писать сразу `__stdcall`. Но <strike>во-первых, это красиво</strike> смысл в этом макросе все-таки есть. Наличие символа `WINAPI` в объявлении функции сразу указывает что это именно функция WinAPI - в отличие, к примеру, от функций обратного вызова, у которых вместо `WINAPI` стоит `CALLBACK`, и который тоже транслируется в `__stdcall`. Благодаря этим макросам сразу видно назначение функции.